# How to batch toggle comment/uncomment certain rows in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Is there a way, within SSMS or via a third-party app, to select a batch of lines to toggle their commented status?

**Background**: in my query, there are two "search modes" that I want to alternate between.

To do this, I need to comment lines `19`, `107`, `108`, `112`, and uncomment line `232`. Then I need to do the opposite to go back to the other "mode".

Rather than scrolling through the query, is there some way to automate this process?

**Example**:

```
1  --select distinct x.name from (
2  select name, dateofbirth, favouritecolour
3  from classmates
4  where dateofbirth between '01-Mar-1990' and '17-Apr-1995'
5  --)x
6  union all
7  --select distinct x.name from (
8  select name, relationship, location
9  from family
10 where relationship = 'uncle'
11 --)x
```

For full detail, I could have the query like this. If I just wanted the names, I would uncomment lines 1,5,7 and 11.

My real life example is spread across hundreds of lines, and would involve commenting **and** uncommenting as part of the same "transition"

Comment: Why just not make a bit variable that will alternate between both modes?

Comment: I'm not familiar with bit variables. The stuff I have to comment out is just the 
 `select distinct name, somethingelse from ( `      
...  
`) x `  

for two sets of queries and removing some ordering/grouping

Comment: argh, can't figure out this comment markup, the close brackets and x are supposed to be further down from the select and opening brackets.

Comment: @SubqueryCrunch You should post that as an answer with an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to do this is to use a variable:

```
--Searchmode 0 = Path A
--Searchmode 1 = Path B
DECLARE @SearchMode int = 0 --Change this to change path

IF @SearchMode = 0
BEGIN
   SELECT blah
   FROM tableA
END

IF @SearchMode = 1
BEGIN
   SELECT blah
   FROM tableB
END
```

You could also make it a procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.exampleProc @SearchMode int
AS
BEGIN

IF @SearchMode = 0
BEGIN
   SELECT blah
   FROM tableA
END

IF @SearchMode = 1
BEGIN
   SELECT blah
   FROM tableB
END

END
```

Then just execute it and feed in the parameter value like this:

```
EXEC dbo.exampleProc 0
EXEC dbo.exampleProc 1
```

**Edit**:

You could also have the repeated parts of the query always run, then the extra filters only run if `@SearchMode = 1`.  Something like:

```
DECLARE @SearchMode int = 0

select name, dateofbirth, favouritecolour
into #temp
from classmates
where dateofbirth between '01-Mar-1990' and '17-Apr-1995'
union all
select name, relationship, location
from family
where relationship = 'uncle'

IF @SearchMode = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM #temp
END

IF @SearchMode = 1
BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT Name
    FROM #temp
END
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron. That would work, but the disadvantage would be I'd be doubling up on the query, and if I make any changes to the query I'd have to do it twice.

Comment: @ChrisA I posted another possible solution for that.  Side note, there are keyboard shortcuts to do your specific need: `CTRL+A` to highlight all, `CTRL+KU` to un-comment all, `CTRL+Z` to undo (re-comment).  I wouldn't suggest that as an awesomely scale-able choice, but worth mentioning in case you don't know those.  Of course that only works if you don't have any other comments.

Comment: I'm not able to test this where I am right now (the Edit: ... part), but will that temp table only have the "classmates" part of the select or will it have the select after the union too?

Comment: I think that will be perfect for what I need. Thank you :)